# Do verses 73:10, 15:97 and 06:33, which are addressed to the Prophet, also apply to me when people say generally hurtful things to me

Tags: quran, hadith

The verses mentioned in the question are addressed to Holy prophet about when people said hurtful things to/about him.

But many scholars give references to them when they talk about people in today's society passing derogatory/hurtful remarks to our face or behind our back. For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ej4PbPJAHbk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ej4PbPJAHbk

The doubt in my mind is that they were addressed to the Holy Prophet in that specific context (about those particular hurtful things).

Somebody recently said to me that I don't come from rich family with a high social status and am so middle class, don't have a (materialistically) strong background etc.

So do these verses apply in my situation? Where in Quran or hadith is the guidance for me in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prophet is a role model we are supposed to follow. So, whenever Allah says something to the Prophet (SAW) in the Quran, that also applies to us except when there is reason to think it does not.

A principle in tafsir is: The ruling is given according to the generality of the wording, not the specific reason for revelation.

Meaning: If a verse is general in meaning, it applies generally even if it was revealed about a certain context.

It is possible to look at it from the perspective of Qiyas Awlawi as well.

Qiyas Awlawi is when you take a ruling that is explicitly given and show that the current situation deserves that ruling even more.

If the Prophet (the best human) is told to be patient over their statements (which were the worst statements possible), who are you not to be patient over comparatively mild statements while you are nothing compared to the honor of the Prophet?

If the Prophet should be patient, it applies even moreso to you that you should be patient.

However, it is important to note that being patient is the recommended thing to do. It is not obligatory. If someone insults you, it is technically within your right to insult them back to the exact same level. However, it is more pious and fearing of Allah to not do that. What would happen if you went beyond the limit? You would become blameworthy.

Answer (score 1):

All of Quran and Sunnah applies to us unless there is an evidence prohibiting to do so.

> You have an excellent model in the Messenger of Allah, for all who put
> their hope in Allah and the Last Day and remember Allah much. (Surat
> al-Ahzab :21)
>
> You should accept whatever the Messenger gives you and abandon
> whatever he tells you to abandon. (Surat al-Hashr: 7)

Comment: But what about the context? I the case of the verses, it is for the cause of Islam and the matter is the disbelievers rejecting faith. In my case, it is a person generally passing derogatory remarks.

Comment: Don't you have that context now? Allah is teaching his messenger how to react and respond to the enemies of Islam. Don't we have enemies of Islam today? We need to react the way Messenger of Allah reacted to the enemies of Islam. Hence it is a teaching for us also.

Comment: JazakAllah for your answers. Actually i mentioned in the question that i want to ask if it applies to my situation.

Comment: وأنتم فجزاكم الله خيرا